# Runnable wont run

Tags: java, android, multithreading

im trying to check when my user stop scrolling.

To this i use this method:

```
commentsLayout.setScrollViewListener(new ScrollViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(WallScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
                    int oldx, int oldy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                oldCommentsYDiefference = oldy;
                commentsYDiefference = y;

                             //do something
}
```

I noticed that when the user stop scrolling the difference between `oldCommentsYDiefference`  and `commentsYDiefference` is always 1.

So in order to check when my user stop scrolling i thought about creating a thread that checks when the difference of this two number is 1 by using this code:

```
public void checkFromScrolling()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.i("commentsYDiefference", commentsYDiefference+"");
                Log.i("oldCommentsYDiefference", oldCommentsYDiefference+"");

                if(commentsYDiefference - oldCommentsYDiefference == 1 || oldCommentsYDiefference - commentsYDiefference == 1)
                {

                    if(checkWallScroll)
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                                         //do things

                            oldCommentsYDiefference = commentsYDiefference;

                            checkWallScroll = true;

                            }
                    }, 2000);

                    checkWallScroll = false;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I call `checkFromScrolling()`in my onCreate.

My problem is that the Runnable is running only once and not all the time.
I know this because i get only one call in my Log reports for

```
Log.i("commentsYDiefference", commentsYDiefference+"");
Log.i("oldCommentsYDiefference", oldCommentsYDiefference+"");
```

How to make Runnable  run all the time the activity is open?

Comment: your log statement is not inside runnable run method.

Comment: yes it is. its inside  public void run() {=

Comment: replace `//do things` by log statments and then try

Comment: do you see the log now??

Answer (score 0):

You could add a while-loop checking if a boolean variable (keepRunning) is true. And then you have to set it to false before your activity is closed.